# ' unsorting ' array - get array back to state before .sort javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

If i have an arraylist and sort it with :

```
myArrayList.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b });
```

is it possible to get 'myArrayList' back to the order it was before the .sort  happend without having a backup of the unsorted array ?  undo sort, so to speak.

Comment: you want to undo sorting? I think you will need to take a backup of previous array before doing sorting. You can't retreive state that is not stored.

Comment: yes, i want to undo sorting. preferable without a backup if possible.

Comment: When you sort, previous arrangement of items are lost and it is not remembered. Unless you take a backup, you can't undo to previous state.

Comment: that's noted - thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with a previously made copy with [`Array#slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) like this, **before sorting**.

> The `slice()` method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object.

```
var myArrayListCopy = myArrayList.slice();
```

```js
var myArrayList = [1000, 5, 2, 8, 42, 101, 111, 20],
    myArrayListCopy = myArrayList.slice(); // make copy from unsorted array first

document.write('<pre>original ' + JSON.stringify(myArrayList, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
myArrayList.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; });
document.write('<pre>sorted ' + JSON.stringify(myArrayList, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
myArrayList = myArrayListCopy; // assign backup
document.write('<pre>from backup ' + JSON.stringify(myArrayList, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: @AndersPedersen, please see edit. make the copy before sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Direct answer is

> 'No, it doesn't'

Because, the final result after sorting is corresponding to the logic that you have done for sorting and you cannot trust it for always will be reversible when some kind of logical action if you added.
Because you dont have any historical data to compare (if it is dynamic)

> Make a copy of the array before you sort it.

Comment: copy that! - no pun intended